# SOS.dll ObjSize and DumpObject under the hood intricacies. How to recreate SOS.dll in C#?

Tags: c#, memory, reflection, sos

This question is largely based on my previous post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322660/using-reflection-to-determine-which-fields-are-backing-fields-of-a-property).

I'm attempting to recreate some of the functionality of the SOS.dll using reflection. Specifically the `ObjSize` and `DumpObject` commands. I use reflection to find all the fields and then if the fields are primitive types I add the size of the primitive type to the overall size of the object. If the field is a value type, then I recursively call the original method and walk down the reference tree until I've hit all primitive type fields.

I'm consistently getting object sizes larger than SOS.dll ObjSize command by a factor of two or so. One reason I've found is that my reflection code seems to be finding fields that SOS is ignoring. For example in a Dictionary, SOS find's the following fields:

- buckets
- entries
- count
- version
- freeList
- freeCount
- comparer
- keys
- values
- _syncRoot
- m_siInfo

However my reflection code finds all of the above and also finds:

- VersionName
- HashSizeName
- KeyValuePairsName
- ComparerName

Also, I'm getting confused regarding the inconsistencies found in the SOS ObjSize and DumpObject commands. I know DumpObject doesn't look at the size of the referenced types. However when I call Object size on the dictionary mentioned above I get:

- Dictionary - 532B

Then I call DumpObject on the Dictionary to get the memory address of it's reference types. Then when I call Objsize on it's reference types I get:

- buckets - 40
- entries - 364
- comparer - 12
- keys - 492
- (the rest are null or primitive)

**Shouldn't the ObjSize on the top level dictionary roughly be the sum of all the ObjSizes on fields within the dictionary? Why is Reflection finding more fields that DumpObject? Any thoughts on why my reflection analysis is returning numbers larger than SOS.dll?**

Also, I never got an answer to one of my questions asked in the thread linked above. I was asking whether or not I should ignore properties when evaluating the memory size of an object. The general consensus was ignore them. However, I found a good example of when a property's backing field would not be included in the collection returned from Type.GetFields(). When looking under the hood of a String you have the following:

Object contains Property named FirstChar
Object contains Property named Chars
Object contains Property named Length
Object contains Field named m_stringLength
Object contains Field named m_firstChar
Object contains Field named Empty
Object contains Field named TrimHead
Object contains Field named TrimTail
Object contains Field named TrimBoth
Object contains Field named charPtrAlignConst
Object contains Field named alignConst
The `m_firstChar` and `m_stringLength` are the backing fields of the Properties `FirstChar` and `Length` but the actual contents of the string are held in the Chars property. This is an indexed property that can be indexed to return all the chars in the String but I can't find a corresponding field that holds the characters of a string.

**Any thoughts on why that is? Or how to get the backing field of the indexed property? Should indexed properties be included in the memory size?**

Answer (score 5):

Well, your Reflection code is broken.  The 4 members you mention (VersionName etc) are not fields, they are private constants.  I'm guessing you are using Type.GetMembers() instead of Type.GetFields() and not checking the returned MemberInfo.MemberType properly.  Just use GetFields() instead.

Do note that you can never get the correct size of a managed object.  The layout of the object is undiscoverable.  The size is not the sum of the fields, fields are *aligned*.  Pretty similar to the StructLayout.Pack property.  Alignment can create holes in the layout, so-called "padding bytes".  As well as extra padding at the end to get fields aligned when the class object is stored in an array.

The fact that layout is not discoverable is actually taken advantage of by the CLR.  It will *swap* fields if a later field fits in the padding between two other fields.  Producing a smaller object than what you'd get if you knew the alignment rules.  Trying to reverse-engineer this is a perilous endeavor, it also depends on the architecture (x86 vs x64 vs Arm).

SOS.dll doesn't have that problem, it has direct access to the internal data that the CLR maintains for a class.  Off limits to managed code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I assure you, I am using Type.GetFields(). I'd be happy to share with you every member of a dictionary I've found using Reflection. Those four members are listed as Fields. 


I understand that the size of an object in memory is a very inconsistent thing in the real world. I'm more looking for an approximation. That's interesting information regarding alignment. Do you have any online resources handy where I can read more about this? Does this imply that my code will give the worst case scenario size but the CLR will ultimately optimize and "shrink" the object?